# Help with Watir Scripting with Tables and Logical Operator

Tags: ftp, watir

I'm brand new to Watir testing and need your advice on a problem that I'm encountering. I can't show you the page since it isn't a public site, but I'll give you a similar table that may help you picture the problem.

**Sample Table :**

```
Begin Month     Protocol    Result
09/2003         HTTP        SUCCESS
09/2003         FTP         SUCCESS
01/2004         HTTP        SUCCESS
08/2011         FTP         FAIL
```

Each Protocol cell is a clickable, dynamic link with a

> `href=javascript:submitForm('/<servlet
>   path>/viewinfo?viewId=<dynamic id>').`

I will be the one generating the 08/2011, FTP link and that is the one that I want to click on.

**Problem :**

- There are no HTML tags of id or name so I can't use those to instruct Watir what to click.
- I can't use straight text of FTP because there is already an existing one before it. Watir would click on the first one I believe.
- I can't always use the href link because the dynamic ID could change to be a different number all the time.

I would think I need a logical operator condition check like below.  Any suggestions?  Thank you for your help.

```
if cell(Begin Month == 08/2011) && cell(Protocol == FTP)<br>
  click that FTP dynamic link<br>
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
browser.link(:after?, browser.cell(:text => "08/2011")).click
```

or this

```
browser.link(:text => "FTP", :after? => browser.cell(:text, "08/2011")).click
```

Sources: [Ways Available To Identify HTML Element](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Ways+Available+To+Identify+HTML+Element), [Multiple Attributes](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Multiple+Attributes)

Answer (score 0):

All of the text shares is within a row of the table, thus can be used to match the row based on :text

You could identify the row you want via a regular expression , then the cell within that row based on it's text.

```
browser.row(:text, /08\/2011FTP/).cell(:text, 'FTP').click
```

potentially there might be a space between the columns (try a puts of the .text of a table row to see) hard to know without seeing your HTML.

if you need to create the regex based on data you read in, then read up on ruby's 'regex' function that lets you create a regular expression from a string